# C++ Windows API DlgDirList sometimes don't return the correct listing

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, directory-listing, file-listing

I have 2 List Box, one always listing directories from a path and other listing the files from the selected directory.

The first time i select a directory, the files are shown properly, but if i select another directory, it lists nothing.

That's my current main.cpp, where all GUI stuff happens: http://pastebin.com/PjSb8aKy

List Box codes goes from lines 31 to 45 and 150 to 165.

Thanks in advance.

--------------------------------------------------**EDIT**---------------------------------------------------------------

I put a simple `std::cout` on the `sel` string, the result is that on the first directory i select, it's "*", then it becomes "DirectoryName\", i tried changing the sel string to be "./DirectoryName", didn't managed to do it, the "\" still appears, but that isn't what bothers me, the real weird stuff is the first selection returning "*" to the `sel` string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the clue is in the docs for the `DlgDirList` function:

> If lpPathSpec specifies a directory, DlgDirListComboBox changes the
>   current directory to the specified directory before filling the list
>   box.

I've never used these functions myself but I'd bet that your current directory is being modified and so subsequent calls to `DlgDirList` are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, current directory from the first list is being constantly changed, but these changes are being handled on lines 31 to 45.

Comment: @Conflux Handled how? I don't see any calls to `SetCurrentDirectory` that would be setting it back to the original location.

Comment: Ok, that's starting to make sense.

But i already tried to make it a relative path, didn't worked well, as you can see on my edit.

I tried to undo the relative path and use `SetCurrentDirectory(dir)` after the populating of the first list(lines 150 to 165), changed literally nothing.

Doing it on the selection changing handler doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I think if you just go back to the parent path after it's been changed the first time it should work (e.g. `SetCurrentDirectory(L"..");`), although you could also use an absolute path which would avoid confusion.